# EGL Driver message (Error) eglQueryDeviceAttribEXT: Bad attribute

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium-chromedriver, webdriverwait, egl

We are getting error below when the chrome browser gets lunched  and any view on the issue below where chrome and selenium, python being used:

```
DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:12306/devtools/browser/14f00afd-581d-4a48-9141-8ab74c3355cf
[1005/210449.408:ERROR:gl_surface_egl.cc(612)] EGL Driver message (Error) eglQueryDeviceAttribEXT: Bad attribute.
[1005/210503.773:ERROR:context_group.cc(151)] ContextResult::kFatalFailure: WebGL2 blacklisted
[1005/210508.959:ERROR:shared_image_manager.cc(120)] SharedImageManager::ProduceGLTexture: Trying to produce a representation from a non-existent mailbox. FB:DB:4B:EB:07:94:DB:D6:D
A:B3:D4:47:9D:AC:5B:83
[1005/210508.960:ERROR:gles2_cmd_decoder.cc(18508)] [.DisplayCompositor]GL ERROR :GL_INVALID_OPERATION : DoCreateAndTexStorage2DSharedImageINTERNAL: invalid mailbox name
[1005/210508.960:ERROR:gles2_cmd_decoder.cc(18529)] [.DisplayCompositor]GL ERROR :GL_INVALID_OPERATION : DoBeginSharedImageAccessCHROMIUM: bound texture is not a shared image
[1005/210508.961:ERROR:gles2_cmd_decoder.cc(10742)] [.DisplayCompositor]RENDER WARNING: texture bound to texture unit 0 is not renderable. It might be non-power-of-2 or have incomp
atible texture filtering (maybe)?
[1005/210508.962:ERROR:gles2_cmd_decoder.cc(18552)] [.DisplayCompositor]GL ERROR :GL_INVALID_OPERATION : DoEndSharedImageAccessCHROMIUM: bound texture is not a shared image
[1005/210509.027:ERROR:gles2_cmd_decoder.cc(18529)] [.DisplayCompositor]GL ERROR :GL_INVALID_OPERATION : DoBeginSharedImageAccessCHROMIUM: bound texture is not a shared image
[1005/210509.028:ERROR:gles2_cmd_decoder.cc(10742)] [.DisplayCompositor]RENDER WARNING: texture bound to texture unit 0 is not renderable. It might be non-power-of-2 or have incomp
atible texture filtering (maybe)?
[1005/210509.028:ERROR:gles2_cmd_decoder.cc(18552)] [.DisplayCompositor]GL ERROR :GL_INVALID_OPERATION : DoEndSharedImageAccessCHROMIUM: bound texture is not a shared image
[1005/210509.673:ERROR:gles2_cmd_decoder.cc(18529)] [.DisplayCompositor]GL ERROR :GL_INVALID_OPERATION : DoBeginSharedImageAccessCHROMIUM: bound texture is not a shared image
[1005/210509.674:ERROR:gles2_cmd_decoder.cc(10742)] [.DisplayCompositor]RENDER WARNING: texture bound to texture unit 0 is not renderable. It might be non-power-of-2 or have incomp
atible texture filtering (maybe)?
[1005/210509.674:ERROR:gles2_cmd_decoder.cc(18552)] [.DisplayCompositor]GL ERROR :GL_INVALID_OPERATION : DoEndSharedImageAccessCHROMIUM: bound texture is not a shared image
10/05/2019 09:05:16 PM ama-cloude webtext:alexa what time is it in hong kong , It's 6:50am.
```

Code trials:

```
import platform , logging
import os,re
from time import  sleep
import selenium.webdriver.support.ui as ui
import selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.webdriver import WebDriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

class Cloud(object):
    """
    Amazon cloud class to get query and response for alexa
    """

    def __init__(self, username='xxxxxxxx', password='xxxx'):

        logging.basicConfig(format='%(asctime)s %(message)s', datefmt='%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p', level=logging.INFO)
        self.logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

        self.url = "https://www.amazon.com"
        self.username = username
        self.password = password
        self.timeout = 100
        self.driver = None
        self.get_chrome_driver()

    def get_chrome_driver(self):
        """
        get chrome driver
        """
        if platform.system().lower() == 'windows':
            if self.driver is None:
                chrome_options = Options()
                #chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-extensions')
                chrome_options.add_argument('--start-maximized')
                chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-popup-blocking')
                chrome_options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')
                chrome_options.add_argument('--allow-insecure-localhost')
                chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-infobars')
                chrome_options.add_argument("--log-level=3")
                chrome_driver_path = os.path.join(str(os.environ['PYTHONPATH'].split(';')[0]),"bin","chromedriver","chromedriver.exe")
                self.driver = WebDriver(executable_path=chrome_driver_path, chrome_options=chrome_options)
        return self.driver

    def login(self, username='xxxxxxxxx', password='xxxxx'):
        """
        Login into amazon cloud
        """
        self.logger.info("logging in amazon cloud username: %s and password: %s" %(self.username, re.sub(r".", "*", self.password)))
        self.driver.get(self.url)
        # wait for login username textbox

        self.wait_visibility_element(By.XPATH, "//div[@id='nav-signin-tooltip']//span[@class='nav-action-inner'][contains(text(),'Sign in')]")
        self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("  //div[@id='nav-signin-tooltip']//span[@class='nav-action-inner'][contains(text(),'Sign in')]").click()

        self.wait_visibility_element(By.XPATH,"//label[@class='a-form-label']")

        self.wait_visibility_element(By.XPATH,"//input[@id='ap_email']")
        username_textbox = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='ap_email']")
        username_textbox.clear()
        username_textbox.send_keys(self.username)  
        self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='continue']").click() 
        self.wait_visibility_element(By.XPATH,"//input[@id='ap_password']")  #//label[@class='a-form-label']

        password_textbox = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='ap_password']")
        password_textbox.clear()
        password_textbox.send_keys(self.password)
        # click on submit button
        self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='signInSubmit']").click()


    def wait_visibility_element(self, by_type, element_name):
        """
        wait for visibility of element
        :param by_type: Locate element using type of element
        :param element_name: element name
        """
        ui.WebDriverWait(self.driver, self.timeout).until(
            EC.visibility_of_element_located((by_type, element_name)))
```

Answer (score 2):

This error message...

```
ERROR:gl_surface_egl.cc(668)] EGL Driver message (Error) eglQueryDeviceAttribEXT: Bad attribute.
```

...is defined in [gl_surface_egl.cc](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/ui/gl/gl_surface_egl.cc#674) as follows:

```
static void EGLAPIENTRY LogEGLDebugMessage(EGLenum error,
                       const char* command,
                       EGLint message_type,
                       EGLLabelKHR thread_label,
                       EGLLabelKHR object_label,
                       const char* message) {
  std::string formatted_message = std::string("EGL Driver message (") +
                  GetDebugMessageTypeString(message_type) +
                  ") " + command + ": " + message;
```

---

### Deep Dive

As per the documentation in [List of Chromium Command Line Switches](https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/) the argument [`--use-gl`](https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/ui/gl/gl_switches.cc?q=kUseGL&sq=package:chromium&type=cs&l=97) selects which implementation of GL the GPU process should be used and the available options are:

- *desktop*: whatever desktop OpenGL the user has installed (Linux and Mac default).
- *egl*: whatever EGL / GLES2 the user has installed (Windows default - actually ANGLE).
- *swiftshader*: The SwiftShader software renderer.

This *DEBUG* message is not harmful and you can continue with your tests.

---

### Solution

However as per best practices, if your usecase involves invoking `click()` instead of using `visibility_of_element_located()` you need to induce *WebDriverWait* for the `element_to_be_clickable()` as follows:

```
def wait_clickability_element(self, by_type, element_name):
    """
    wait for clickability of element
    :param by_type: Locate element using type of element
    :param element_name: element name
    """
    ui.WebDriverWait(self.driver, self.timeout).until(
        EC.element_to_be_clickable((by_type, element_name)))
```

---

### Additional consideration

Possibly this error is caused by the app getting launched by `ES2-only` devices, even though the manifest requires `ES`3 capability. Updating `EGL_RENDERABLE_TYPE` from `EGL_OPENGL_ES2_BIT` to **`EGL_OPENGL_ES3_BIT`** will solve this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Disabling gpu on chrome solved this error.

```py
from selenium import webdriver
chrome_opt = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_opt.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
path = r"D:/tools/chromedriver/chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=path,chrome_options=chrome_opt)
...
```

rerunning the script with the above options did not cause the above error message.